# How to redirect non-www domain.com to www domain.com(WordPress blog) in AWS Route 53?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, url-rewriting, redirect, amazon-route53

I have my non-www domain.com with GoDaddy and my WordPress Blog is hosted in AWS EC2. I'm using Route 53 to handle DNS requests. The existing solution for my question, seen in many places(including SOF) is to create two S3 buckets in the name of non-www domain and www domain for redirection of static websites. This is not my case.

I've my WordPress installed in EC2 and not using S3 for holding my Data. I hope this is not a static website and cannot follow the general solutions available.

**I tried the following solution around and did not work**

- I tried changing the C-NAME record to www.domain.com but it did not worked.
- I tried domain forward feature available with GoDaddy.com and didn't work.
- I tried modifying .htaccess file and that too didn't work.

This is what my record sets in Route 53 look like

```
Name          Type     Value                         TTL
------        -----    -----                         ----
domain.com.    A      xx.xx.xxx.xxx  (EIP)           300
domain.com.    MX     1 ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM           3600
                      5 ALT1.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM 
                      5 ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM 
                      10 ALT3.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM 
                      10 ALT4.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM    
domain.com.    NS     ns-27.awsdns-03.com.           172800
                      ns-1190.awsdns-20.org. 
                      ns-2028.awsdns-61.co.uk. 
                      ns-855.awsdns-42.net.     
domain.com.    SOA    xxxxxxxxx                      900
```

How can I redirect my domain.com to www.domain.com?

Comment: In GoDaddy, did you change the nameservers (NS) to the four provided by AWS Route 53 hosted zones? Use www.whatsmydns.net to troubleshoot what NS are resolving your domain name. Also, change your TTL to 60 seconds so the changes will propagate faster.

Comment: Yes, I did change the NS(as given above). And whatsmydns.net is pointed to the correct EIP.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. When you modified your .htaccess file did you modify your httpd.conf file as well? Can you provide the your configs?

Comment: This is what I added to my .htaccess file(removed it because it failed loading the site after adding this - is this correct for my AWS configuration)

RewriteEngine on
  rewritecond %{http_host} ^ec2instances.info [nc]
  rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.ec2instances.info/$1 [r=301,nc]


I haven't modified my httpd.conf file.

Comment: Okay - there are actually many ways to redirect but this is a limitation of AWS Route 53 - I don't think there is a way to direct a naked domain. So, you will need to do the rewrite on your web server and I'm assuming you are running Apache. I can't run you through the steps right now cause I'm travelling but take a look at this site that explains different ways to redirect - I think Method 5 is what you want: http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/ApacheRedirect.html#APACHE

Comment: Thanks for your time. I will check this solution and get back to you. Why can't you put this as an answer rather than a comment. There by, if this solution(source) will be helpful for others as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was hesitant to post my comment as an answer because there are a gazillion ways to setup and configure Wordpress it seems. Anyway, to keep in the spirit of keeping this question in the *amazon-web-services* tag I ran a test case deploying from the AWS Wordpress Cloudformation template. I'm not sure if this is how you actually installed Wordpress but here is ***one*** way to redirect:

[image]

Make sure that your Cloudformation template completes successfully.

[image]

Here is what my Hosted Zone looked like - I have not added A records yet.

[image]

Get the instance IP address. Note that in this example I did not setup an Elastic IP. Since I knew that I would not need to stop the instance temporarily I opted to just stick with the automatically assigned, random pubic IP.

[image]

Next I made an A record for the domain apex of that IP and then an A record for www. I also changed the TTL to 60 seconds.

[image]

Once DNS propagation completed I tried accessing my domain name. As you can see, the AWS Cloudformation Wordpress installation defaults to a different path and URL.

[image]

Using the URL, http://example.com/wordpress did the trick.

[image]

I didn't go through the steps but when you go to http://example.com/wordpress it starts a setup screen. Enter all the information like DB name and password, etc. and then login to the admin panel. Once you go through all of that you go to the General settings screen. This is where your configuration will probably be different but for mine, the URLs were listed as http://example.com/wordpress. I simply changed these URLs to http://www.example.com/wordpress. (As an aside, I also tried changing and saving the permalink section to generate an .htaccess file but one was not generated due to the inability to write to the file. I tried making my own but I kept running into "too many redirect" messages so this might not be a route you want to take depending on your install.)

[image]

You will need to make a change in the index.php file. For my installation it was located at /var/www/html/wordpress/index.php. Make sure to make a copy before changing it. I simply added /wordpress/ in front of wp-blog-header.php. Again, this install puts the Wordpress files in the directory /wordpress - your install will probably be different.

[image]

Next you need to copy that modified index.php file to /var/www/html/ and then restart the httpd service.

[image]

To test the change I cleared out my DNS cache and opened up the network section of developer tools in Chrome.

[image]

I then opened a new tab (have to open developer tools again) and then typed in the naked domain name.

[image: Developer tools result]

As you can see, the URL redirected to www.example.com with a 301 permanent redirect.

[image]

I'll through another suggestion out here while I'm at it. You can use the free version of Cloudflare to just do the redirect for you. Cloudflare offers a bunch of other free and useful services like CDN so if you don't mind depending on a 3rd party service (a reputable one by the way) it might be easier with more value add. As I highlighted in the screenshot however, note that if you use forwarding you cannot use some of the other advanced rule sets.

[image: Cloudflare redirect screen example]

Anyway, I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks @VirtualJJ for a detailed answer. It didn't worked initially even after making all the changes at Route53. Only after correcting the URLS under WordPress url settings, the domain got the www.domain finally. Awarding you the answered credit for this question. Thank you.